# Xamarin - Swap StackLayouts dynamically

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is there a way to replace an existing Stacklayout with another Stacklayout dynamically after clicking a button. What I am trying to do is display a search bar or entry filed next to a picker but it does not fit in stacklayout if a phone has a smaller screen. So I was hoping to add a button which will remove picker and display entry or search bar instead and when "cancel" button is clicked it should show picker again. Please help.

Comment: the easiest approach would be to place both layouts on the page, but just toggle their visibility so that only one is visible at a time

Comment: @Jason, a second approach is to create the UI in the code behind which might not be the best in terms of readability.

Comment: @Jason thank you. I got it working.